# Opencv 4.6 python 3.10 ошибка с изображением

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pycharm

При запуске кода выдает ошибку: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'. Различно редактировал путь к изображению, менял формат изображения, помещал в сам проект, пробовал другие изображения, одна и та же ошибка появляется.

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui as pg
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
template = cv2.imread('D://pythonProject3/images/obrezok.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        loc = np.where(res >= 0.7)
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(frame, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == 27:
          break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Вроде в Windows в пути используются "\", а не "/". И тут не "D://", а "D:\"

Comment: Уже пробовал, разницы нету.

Comment: gray_frame и gray разные  переменные...

Comment: а так: 'D://pythonProject3//images//obrezok.jpg' или 'D:/pythonProject3/images/obrezok.jpg'

Comment: Я путь к изображению уже всевозможными способами включая этот исправлял, серовно ошибка.

Comment: Мне кажется у Вас переменная  frame пустая, поэтому он не может ее превратить в бинарное в методе cvtColor